# How to customize the groove of QSlider

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5, qslider

Is there any way to customize the groove of `QSlider`? I want to colorize some part of groove based on some value. I try `setStyleSheet()` but it's not working as I have expected.

My similar question was asked before [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30678-customize-the-groove-of-qslider).

**Like this**:
[image]

Based on a range like 10, 20 is invalid range and must be red.

Comment: could you show images of what you want to get

Comment: @eyllanesc, I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find this [link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/96055/qslider-customize-bug/4) useful. This problem relates to [QLinearGradient](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlineargradient.html) of the groove.

I hope it helps.